# how to add web element into list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the below code I'm extracting emails id and storing in the list in python

```
chrome_driver_path = os.path.abspath('..')  + "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.airindia.in/contact-details.htm")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

doc = driver.page_source

emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', doc)
list_new = []
for email in emails:
    list_new.extend(str(email))
    #print(email)

print("total emails - ",len(list_new))

driver.quit()

print(list_new)
```

but getting the output as `['c', 'a', 'l', 'l', '.', 'd', 'e', 'l', '@', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'i', 'n']`

I need output as `['call.del@airindia.in','airindiaretros.ai@iclployalty.com']`

I'm new to selenium python

sample code with my console output https://github.com/venkywarriors619/selenium_with_python/blob/master/Python_basics/SeleniumWebDriver_Advanced/RegularExpression.py

Comment: What is the output of 
    print("total emails - ",len(list_new))
Does it show one email address or many?

Comment: https://github.com/venkywarriors619/selenium_with_python/blob/master/Python_basics/SeleniumWebDriver_Advanced/RegularExpression.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
list_new.extend(str(email))
```

To:

```
list_new.append(str(email))
```

`append` adds its argument as a single element to the end of a list. The length of the list itself will increase by one.

`extend` iterates over its argument adding each element to the list, extending the list.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.append()` to append elements to a list.

Use `list.extend()` to append a bunch of elements (from a list of elements) to a list

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regex for this purpose. Simply try below to get list of emails:

```
emails = [email.text for email in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('linkText') if "@" in email.text]
```

Answer (score 1):

Extends() should become a list of elements as an input. That is why python threats your String as a list of characters and appends every single one to the list.

You should use append(). I takes one element and appends it on the end of a list.

Also I can recommend you to update your re pattern. I am using this one:

```
re_pattern = r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]+'
```

But take a look at ["Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works"](http://emailregex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You use list.extend() which treats the string as a list of chars. Use list.append() instead to append the string as a single object.